# Make a Gutenberg Block that do WP_User_Query

Tags: block-editor

I want to make a block that functions like the FormTokenField for selecting Category and Tag in the sidebar of the block editor, but query user instead.  After user selects user from it, this block will be saved as a meta block for that post.

Is this possible?  Any idea is welcomed.

Comment: Gutenberg is React base framework and working with data based on Wordpress rest api.
You can see example for working with data in answer for this post:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/363285/how-to-use-getentityrecords-for-user-data