# How to use “getEntityRecords” for user data?

Tags: block-editor

How can I use `getEntityRecords` for user data?

I have read these two posts, and it seems like that an endpoint for user is not included as the default entry for `getEntityRecords` in Gutenberg's source code.

Is it possible to get user data through REST API to Gutenberg?

I have tried with this code, but it return an empty array

```
wp.data.select("core").getEntityRecords('user', 'user')
```

Gutenberg source code: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/e4b5330e61b61b64b7f3354b6a9d9a8c395a9aa9/packages/core-data/src/entities.js#L14

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**So I guess you're still using WordPress version 5.3.x?** :)

Because if so (and I was), then yes, the [users endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/) (at `wp/v2/users`) is not included in the *default entities*.

But you can manually add it:

```js
// Add the endpoint.
wp.data.dispatch( 'core' ).addEntities( [
    {
        name: 'user',
        kind: 'root',
        baseURL: '/wp/v2/users'
    }
] );
```

And that's basically how it's added/[defined](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/e82e81985c2ddd72b24ed3588ffb7e250921512e/packages/core-data/src/entities.js#L59) in WordPress 5.4.

Then to get the entity records, you'd do so, which should work in both WordPress 5.4 and 5.3.x:

```js
// Get multiple records.
wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'root', 'user', { per_page: 3 } );

// Get a single record.
wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecord( 'root', 'user', 123 );
```

### Alternate Options

#### Use `wp.apiRequest()`

Note that it uses `jQuery.ajax()`, so methods like `done()` and `fail()` can be used.

```js
// Multiple records.
wp.apiRequest( { path: 'wp/v2/users', data: { per_page: 3 } } )
    .done( data => console.log( data ) )
    .fail( xhr => console.log( xhr.responseText ) );

// Single record.
wp.apiRequest( { path: 'wp/v2/users/123' } ).done( data => console.log( data ) );
```

#### Or use [`wp.apiFetch()`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/api-fetch)

```js
// Multiple records.
wp.apiFetch( { path: 'wp/v2/users', data: { per_page: 3 } } )
    .then( data => console.log( data ) )
    .catch( data => console.log( data.message ) ); // here, 'data' is an object

// Single record.
wp.apiFetch( { path: 'wp/v2/users/123' } ).then( data => console.log( data ) );
```

But whichever option you use, make sure you enqueue your script with the correct *dependencies* — for `wp.apiRequest()`, the script handle/ID is `wp-api-request`, whereas for `wp.apiFetch()`, it is `wp-api-fetch`.

Happy coding!

---

### Update

In reply to your comment, yes, `getEntityRecords()` returns a `null` if the API request is not yet resolved (e.g. the browser is still receiving the response from the server).

So you can't simply do `result = wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( ... )` and expect the `result` to be always assigned with the response of the API request.

Instead, `getEntityRecords()` should be used with `wp.data.select( 'core/data' ).isResolving()` like so:

```js
const { isResolving } = wp.data.select( 'core/data' );

// The last argument is the three arguments you passed to getEntityRecords().
isResolving( 'core', 'getEntityRecords', [ 'root', 'user', { per_page: 3 } ] );
```

Examples:

1. Using `wp.data.subscribe()`:

   ```js
   const { subscribe, select } = wp.data;

   // Fetch users list.
   const query = { per_page: 3 };
   select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'root', 'user', query );

   const unsubscribe = subscribe( () => {
       const { isResolving } = select( 'core/data' );
       const args = [ 'root', 'user', query ];

       if ( isResolving( 'core', 'getEntityRecords', args ) ) {
           console.log( 'still resolving' );
       } else {
           const data = select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'root', 'user', query );
           console.log( 'data received', data );

           // We're done, so let's unsubscribe from the isResolving() check above.
           unsubscribe();
       }
   } );
   ```
2. Using `wp.data.withSelect()`:

   ```js
   const { withSelect } = wp.data;
   const { createElement: el } = wp.element;

   const MyComponent = withSelect( select => {
       const { isResolving } = select( 'core/data' );
       const query = { per_page: 3 };
       return {
           users: select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'root', 'user', query ),
           isRequesting: isResolving( 'core', 'getEntityRecords', [ 'root', 'user', query ] )
       };
   } )( props => {
       if ( props.isRequesting ) { // still resolving; so display a "loading" indicator
           return el( 'div', null, 'Loading data..' );
       }

       const list = props.users.map( user => el( 'li', { key: user.id }, user.name ) );
       return el( 'ul', null, list );
   } );

   // Then somewhere use el( MyComponent ) to render the custom element above.
   ```

And basically, if you're creating a Gutenberg element, then you'd want to use `getEntityRecords()` with `withSelect()`.

I hope that helps. :)

Comment: This is really helpful!  I have updated to 5.4 and tried that code, but it only returns null.  I have tried it multiple times to ensure it is not the null that I may get for the first call.  What did I missed?


The code I tried to use:
`const result = wp.data.select("core").getEntityRecords('root', 'user', { per_page: 3 });
console.log(result);`

Comment: Wait no this is working, but it only works when I type it into the console.  Why was that???

Comment: Check the "Update" part in the answer. :)

Comment: Dear Sally CJ, thank you very march for your answer!!!
I'm study gutenberg, but never hear about this methods.
Now one of the my big problem - is working with data.

Please, say me - how you know about working with data ?

Comment: @GayratVlasov, I basically referred to the [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/), the official [examples](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples/) and the source code like the [Latest Posts block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library/src/latest-posts). There are also various tutorials you can find via Google.. :) Good luck!

Comment: For me, `props.isRequesting` was always false, even if there wasn’t any data yet. So I changed the if clause to `if ( ! props.users )` and omitted the `isRequesting`.

Comment: Oddly, this method is acting strangely for custom collections. I created an endpoint for nav-menus that lists out nav menus, and while everything works with the api response (it lists each menu out), the logged response from the .getEntityRecords request is just the last menu's data, copied over to each of the rest of the items in the array. And adding a number as a third argument doesn't request the single menu route,  just the root!

Comment: @Dtipson from what I could tell, your custom endpoint would need to manually implement the single menu requests, however, that should be asked in another question. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ The endpoint manually lists all defined nav menus in an array: the json response has [{title: 'Menu 1'}, {title:'Menu 2'}, {title:'Menu 3'}] and if I fetch it, works properly. But when I set it up the route with addEntities and then request it with getEntityRecords, the result is an array of the expected length... but every record has been replaced with the last one [{title: 'Menu 3'}, {title:'Menu 3'}, {title:'Menu 3'}]
This might be something I'm doing wrong, or a bug (most of this is not fully documented, and many core blocks just use apiFetch)

Comment: @Dtipson I'm afraid I can't help you any further via this question, so I suggest you to post all that as a new question, and include as much details as possible - the more, the better. Until then, have a good day ahead. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ - I've just raised a new question based on your answer here - any chance you'd be willing to take a peek? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/398471/correctly-handling-wordpress-core-data-retrieval-in-gutenberg

Comment: Sorry @MattWoodward, I was offline, so I wasn't able to help you.. anyway, I'm glad you managed to find a solution. Cheers :)

Comment: As an update, you can now also use `const { records, hasResolved } = useEntityRecords( "root", "user", { per_page: 5 } );` where the final object supports any params in the [user rest endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/).